# Why does my reference not live long enough?

Tags: rust

The code:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

trait DoSomething<T> {
    fn do_sth(&self, value: T);
}

impl<T: Debug> DoSomething<T> for &usize {
    fn do_sth(&self, value: T) {
        println!("{:?}", value);
    }
}

fn foo(b: Box<DoSomething<&i32>>) {
    let s = 123;
    b.do_sth(&s);
}

fn main() {
    foo(Box::new(&3));
}
```

The compiler error message is:

```
error[E0597]: `s` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:15:14
   |
13 | fn foo(b: Box<DoSomething<&i32>>) {
   |        - has type `std::boxed::Box<(dyn DoSomething<&'1 i32> + '_)>`
14 |     let s = 123;
15 |     b.do_sth(&s);
   |     ---------^^-
   |     |        |
   |     |        borrowed value does not live long enough
   |     argument requires that `s` is borrowed for `'1`
16 | }
   | - `s` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I think this `&s` is just used in `foo`, the `foo` method ends and doesn't borrow anymore? But that's not the case. Who's still borrowing it? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever there's a reference in Rust, there's a lifetime. In most cases, the compiler can infer it, so that you don't have to write it down, but it's still there. When you get confusing lifetime errors, it helps to try to figure out what these implicit lifetimes are.

```
fn foo(b: Box<DoSomething<&i32>>) {
    let s = 123;
    b.do_sth(&s);
}
```

This is equivalent to

```
fn foo<'y>(b: Box<DoSomething<&'y i32>>) {
    let s = 123;
    b.do_sth(&s);
}
```

In other words, the lifetime of the reference passed to `do_sth` is actually "whatever the caller of `foo` wants". This function signature allows me to write this main:

```
fn main() {
    let b : Box<DoSomething<&'static i32>> = Box::new(&3);
    foo(b);
}
```

And if you expand the `DoSomething` trait for this parameter, you end up with this function:

```
fn do_sth(&self, value: &'static i32) {
    println!("{:?}", value);
}
```

which `foo` is trying to call with a reference to a local variable.

I hope that explains why your code doesn't work.

As for what you should write instead, I think that's not really answerable in general. There's no way to write the `do_sth` signature in a way that says "all references passed to this function may be transient". You'll have to look at your real code and think of a better way of writing it.

Comment: Thank you, I understand why the compiler report error

Comment: Why `'static`? Won't lifetime elision in this case lead to `fn do_sth<'a>(&'a self, &'a i32)` (due to `self`)?

Comment: @Cerberus: Different parameters get different lifetimes; you are thinking of the fact that the `self` and return reference share the same lifetime in certain cases.

Comment: @Cerberus `'static` is the only lifetime you can name in a function that isn't itself parameterized. Thus it's the one I had to use for the example.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks, seems that I've mistaken the elision rule.